# How to break while loop after 5 attempts?

Tags: bash

How to keep track of how many guesses the user makes and print a message that tells them they lose? Exit after 5 guesses.

```
num=$(( $RANDOM % 100 + 1 ))

while [ "$input" -ne "$num" ]; do
if [ "$input" -gt "$num" ]; then
echo "The number is too high."
read input
elif [ "$input" -lt "$num" ]; then
echo "The number is too low."
read input
fi
done
echo "Great, you picked the right number."
```

Comment: Define a counter variable, initialise it to zero, and increment it by one each time the user provides input in the loop?

Comment: Or, write a for loop over `1..5` and exit early if the user guesses correctly before the 5th iteration.

Comment: Use `break` to exit your loop.

Comment: From there, just whiipe your last `read input`... And place 1st **before** 1st `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(( $RANDOM % 100 + 1 ))

for (( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )); do
    read -p "Enter a number: " input
    if (( input == num )); then
        echo "Great, you picked the right number."
        break
    elif (( input > num )); then
        echo "The number is too high."
    elif (( input < num )); then
        echo "The number is too low."
    fi
done
```

BTW I tested the script by modifying the random number generator to `$RANDOM % 10 + 1` but still not easy :).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Good to know it works. Please enjoy programming. BR.

Comment: I am new to programming and there is a lot to learn about it. Now the good news is your script does work and exits after 5 attempts. I added a line under "done"    echo "Sorry, That was your 5th guess. You lose.  The number is $num."  Thank you for your help. I have a question what is  "i" in "for (( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )); do"

Comment: `i` is a bash variable which holds a numeric value. We can omit the leading dollar sign `$` within `((` and `))`. Try to put a line `echo "$i"` after `done`. It will vary between `0` and `5` depending on the number of retry.